# Project-level conditional compilation constant

Tags: vb.net, conditional-compilation

I am getting a project-level conditional compilation constant error while trying to build my VB.NET project. It reads:

```
project-level conditional compilation constant 'VB_VER=9.0,TARGET="exe",CONFIG="Debug",_MyType="Console",PLATFORM="AnyCPU",DEBUG;^^ ^^ TRACE' not valid: Character is not valid.
```

I recently upgraded it to the latest version (from 2.0), and I have a feeling that this has something to do with it.

What does this mean? I am clueless...

Here is my project file:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="3.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectType>local</ProjectType>
    <ProjectVersion>7.10.3077</ProjectVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{5810CBEF-671E-4845-BBE3-BC3470C3EE18}</ProjectGuid>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <AssemblyName>svchost</AssemblyName>
    <DefaultClientScript>JScript</DefaultClientScript>
    <DefaultHTMLPageLayout>Grid</DefaultHTMLPageLayout>
    <DefaultTargetSchema>IE50</DefaultTargetSchema>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <MyType>Console</MyType>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>0.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <StartupObject>Sub Main</StartupObject>
    <ApplicationManifest>My Project\app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>svchost.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <NoStdLib>false</NoStdLib>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <NoWarn>42016,42017,42018,42019,42032</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>svchost.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <NoStdLib>false</NoStdLib>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <NoWarn>42016,42017,42018,42019,42032</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <!-- Removed Files Here -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <!-- Removed Files Here -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
         <!-- Removed Files Here -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
         <!-- Removed Files Here -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
         <!-- Removed Files Here -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
    </PreBuildEvent>
    <PostBuildEvent>
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: It would help if you open your VB project file with notepad (it's just XML) and paste it in the question. (You might want to trim the references and the actual files to keep it short)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. But after I used "," as the separating character between constants instead of ";", it worked.

So have a try with "," (comma) only.

Comment: My version of dnSpy causes this error when exporting decompiled vb.net. DefineConstants is semi-colon delimited and must be changed.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the DefineConstants tag in this block:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>svchost.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <NoStdLib>false</NoStdLib>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <NoWarn>42016,42017,42018,42019,42032</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to

```
<DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
```

It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

In .vbproj files you must delimit define constants with commas, unlike the semicolons used in .csproj files. So if you want DEBUG and TRACE flags you want:

```
<DefineConstants>DEBUG,TRACE</DefineConstants>
```